# Can't connect to Linux via SSH from PowerGUI

Tags: ssh, powershell

I'm trying to connect to a linux host from Windows via SSH.

I can successfully connect from the Windows PowerShell console with the next command:

```
New-SSHSession -ComputerName ubuntu-018 -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

But when I try to run the same command with the same username and password from PowerGUI, it throws the next error:

[image: PowerGUI error]

I can reproduce the same error message by using an incorrect password in the Windows PowerShell console:

[image: Windows PowerShell error]

I'm sure that I'm using the correct username and password:

[image: successfully connected]

I'd appreciate any guidance of what's going on.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you connect with PuTTY?

Comment: @Burgi yes I can

Comment: Perhaps a PowerGUI bug, be sure you're on the latest version perhaps that's an issue fixed by a newer version of PowerGUI.